# Schema.org validation error (within HTML+Microdata table) for 'leadForm'

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

Creating an email based on content into a lead form and am getting errors from https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/ stating I have an invalid itemtype when the microdata is within tables:

> leadForm (The type leadForm is not a type known to Google.)

The first code block below shows no errors, while the second gets the invalid item type. Why?

**Valid example**

```
<section itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/leadForm">
<p>First Name:<span itemprop="firstName">[first_name]</span></p>
<p>Last Name:<span itemprop="lastName">[last_name]</span></p>
<p>Phone:<span itemprop="phone">[phone]</span></p>
</section>
```

**Invalid itemtype**

```
<section itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/leadForm">
<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="230"><strong>First Name:</strong></td>
      <td width="253"><span itemprop="firstName">[first_name]</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Last Name:</strong></td>
      <td><span itemprop="lastName">[last_name]</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Phone:</strong></td>
      <td><span itemprop="phone">[phone]</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Email:</strong></td>
      <td><span itemprop="email">[email]</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Language Preference:</strong></td>
      <td><span itemprop="lang">[lang]</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Best Time to Contact</strong></td>
      <td><span itemprop="contactPref">[contactPref]</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Comments/Special Instructions:</strong></td>
      <td><span itemprop="comments">[comments]</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`http://schema.org/leadForm` is not a valid type. As it starts with a lowercase letter (`leadForm` instead of `LeadForm`), it would be a property anyway, but this [doesn’t exist](http://schema.org/leadForm).

I think Google’s testing tool should report the same error for the first snippet; it seems to be a glitch that it doesn’t.

Comment: I was under the impression you could use custom itemSource - no?  If not, is there no microdata for a Sales lead form?

Comment: @user1754738: Well, you could create your own vocabulary, but then you have to use your own domain, not `schema.org`. -- If you want to use the vocabulary Schema.org (which is what the big search engines support), you have to use the types they define. See my answer on Webmasters about [how to find a suitable Schema.org type](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/92108/17633).